# Reading object from file regardless type, inferring reading method from generic type

Tags: java, file, generics

I'm currently working on a file based repository and I'm trying to make it generic. The dilemma is how I can read from file in a suitable way. 
I tried creating an interface like

```
public interface SerializableToFile<T> {

  Callable<T> objectFromFileLine(String fileLine, String delimiter);
}
```

and implemented it in each object of the domain, like

```
  public Callable<LabProblem> objectFromFileLine(String fileLine, String delimiter){
    return () -> {
      String[] components = fileLine.split(delimiter);
      LabProblem newEntity = new LabProblem(Integer.parseInt(components[1]), components[2]);
      newEntity.setId(Long.parseLong(components[0]));
      return newEntity;
    };

  }
```

And Repository be generic extending SerializableToFile, like

```
FileRepository<T extends SerializableToFile>
```

Now, the question is, how can I use the objectFromFileLine method to read my file to a array of Ts? I need to find a way to call my method on each line, but I really cannot figure out how I can call T.objectFromFileLine or something like this (static doesn't seem to work). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are searching for something like this:

```
public class FileRepository {
    public <T extends SerializableToFile> List<T> readAllLines(File file, SerializableToFile<T> serializableToFile) throws Exception {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String line : lines) {
            result.add(serializableToFile.objectFromFileLine(line, " ").call());
        }
    }
}
```

You need to pass in the converter as a reference (`serializableToFile`) so the method knows how to convert your data.